# How to get compiler with a token ? (Premake)

Tags: premake

I want to get the name of the compiler (e.g. vs2015) to use it in a path.
For example, `cfg.buildcfg` returns Debug or Release. I want something which returns vs2015, clang, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use a couple of different values. [cfg.toolset](https://github.com/premake/premake-core/wiki/toolset) will return the toolset as one of `msc`, `gcc`, or `clang`. [_ACTION](https://github.com/premake/premake-core/wiki/_ACTION) will return the action as specified on the command line `vs2015`, `gmake`, etc.